# Look up JS array from database result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple database table (*entries*) with a couple of columns, *name* and *classes*.

There is also a javascript array as follows:

```
function EntryClass(type, attr, classname, desc, price) {this.type = type;this.attr = attr;this.classname = classname;this.desc = desc;this.price = price;}
var cls = [
  new EntryClass("", "", "", 0),
  new EntryClass("simple", "adult", "Class 1 Name", "Cls1 Desc", 100),
  new EntryClass("advanced", "junior", "Class 2 Name", "Cls2 Desc", 200),
  ...
]
```

I've selected all the rows from my table:

```
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY name ASC') as $row) {
  echo '<h3>'.$row['name'].'</h3>';
  echo '<p>'.$row['classes'].'</p>';
}
```

Because of how the database was populated, the 'classes' field in the database is a string of integers. For example: 1 3 7

Rather than just echo the list of numbers, I'm trying to do a lookup against the class name (from the javascript array) so I can echo:

Class 1 Name

Class 3 Name

Class 7 Name

where it'll show the class name not just the number.

It can safely be done by the position of the row in the javascript array (hence the empty first EntryClass in array).

My guess is that it could be done by echoing the class number (would have the split the string and echo them in a loop), after which a JS function can run to swap the number for the full class name. However, I'm a little stuck how to do this. Or, if there's a better way!

Any help / advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so `$row['classes']` is `1 3 7`?

Comment: so what EXACTLY do yo want?

Comment: Is that PHP? Are you passing data to javascript with AJAX? Why aren't you using JSON?

Comment: oh i think i got it. the database lists the id of the classes. in the javascript array you got the information for a class. its 1 entrie>n classes

Comment: Yes $row.['classes'] is 1 3 7 (for example).  Zove, I don't know - I have no idea how best to proceed. I think making a table in the database out of the array is probably the most straight forward but I wanted to see how it could be done by editing the page with js after the echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description sounds like the classes are only defined in your javascript.  You would need to have a php equivalent.

```
$classes =  array(
    0 => array("type" => "", "attr" => "", "classname" => "", "desc" => "", "price" => 0),
    1 => array("type" => "simple", "attr" => "adult", "classname" => "Class 1 Name", "desc" => "Cls1 Desc", "price" => 100),
    2 => array("type" => "simple", "attr" => "adult", "classname" => "Class 2 Name", "desc" => "Cls2 Desc", "price" => 200)
);

foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY name ASC') as $row) {
    echo "<h3>" . $row['name'] . "</h3>";
    foreach(explode($row['classes'], " ") as $class_id) {
        // You may want to test if $class_id is a valid key first
        echo "<p>Class " . $class_id . " " . $classes[$class_id]["classname"] . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it this way as it was by far the quickest and simplest. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works. But the problem is that you do post processing. Not the best solution. Also the id points to the array position. Maybe think about an ID in your EntryClass and a function getClassNameById. Or do it in PHP only if that is an option.

```
    $(document).ready(function($) {

        function EntryClass(type, attr, classname, desc, price) {
            this.type = type;
            this.attr = attr;
            this.classname = classname;
            this.desc = desc;
            this.price = price;
        }

        var cls = [
            new EntryClass("", "", "", 0),
            new EntryClass("simple", "adult", "Class 1 Name", "Cls1 Desc", 100),
            new EntryClass("advanced", "junior", "Class 2 Name", "Cls2 Desc", 200)
        ];

        var $classes = $('.classes');
        $classes.each( swapClassName );
        function swapClassName(){
            var classStr = '';
            var classIds = this.innerHTML.split(' '); // will get an array of IDs

            // walk IDs
            for( var i = 0; i < classIds.length; i++ ) {
                //get the name on position <classIds[i]>
                classStr += cls[classIds[i]].classname+'<br>';
            };

            this.innerHTML = classStr;
        }

    });
```